# SQL Server Columns are equal but showing not equal. How are they different?

Tags: sql, sql-server, checksum

I have the following code

```
select 
    Name, UniqueId, 
    checksum(Name) as CheckName, 
    checksum(UniqueId) as CheckId
from 
    DataManagementPipeline.dbo.pod_1801_energex_vegetation_zones 
where 
   Name <> UniqueId
```

The results are the following

```
Name        UniqueId        CheckName      CheckId
********************************************************
VZ-4820/73  VZ-4820/73     -1880307869     -21513965
VZ-400706   VZ-400706       591267130      536293334
```

The values are the same (white space and all) yet they are appearing as different and interestingly the checksums are different. Is it an encoding issue as to why they are different? Any ideas?

Comment: I think datatype for  " Name, UniqueId," is nvarchar.

Comment: The datatypes are both varchar. Name is varchar(max) and UniqueId is varchar(100). But both strings are obviously less that this so it should not make a difference.

Comment: If this condition "Name <> UniqueId"  satisfies values will not be retrieved as of my knowledge...how can u generate output for this

Comment: That is the mystery. They are the same values in notepad++, etc. They look the same, yet they satisfy <> . The checksum shows something is strange but I can not put my finger on it.

Comment: If both datatype are same ,the values retrieved in output will be same
     Name            UniqueId    CheckName      CheckId
VZ-4820/73 VZ-4820/73 1347317154 1347317154
VZ-400706 VZ-400706 1426899811 1426899811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHECKSUM` will return different values, if the types are different. See more at [MSDN Checksum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx). I think in your case, *Name* & *UniqueId* are of different types. Please see the example code below

```
CREATE TABLE test(origname varchar(36), uniqueid nvarchar(36))

INSERT INTO test(origname,uniqueid)
values ('venkat',N'venkat')

SELECT CHECKSUM(origname), CHECKSUM(uniqueid) FROM test

-- Returned Values 
178987073   1792344567
```

Comment: Name and UniqueId are varchar(max) and varchar(100) respectively.

Comment: I have tried with ur case as"varchar(max) and varchar(100) ". I can able to get the output where as vales are same

Comment: The fact that they are both varchar and the same size should not make them unequal. So the mystery continues.

Comment: @Raja Yuvi are you saying that they satisfy <> and are thus returned or they do not satisfy <>?

Comment: @EmptyWaterHoles if " Name <> UniqueId"  values should not be retrieved , if " Name = UniqueId"  the values retrieved will/must be same.

Comment: However that is not happening as expected. There is something underlying that is not equal. I should add that I created Name via ogr2ogr and then UniqueId was added by alter table after.

Answer (score 1):

The mystery solved is that the spacing on the end of UniqueId was ASCII character(10) and the not the white space I thought it was. Hence why they were coming up as not equal. So i added this code

```
ltrim(rtrim(Name)) <> rtrim(ltrim(REPLACE(REPLACE(UniqueId, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')))
```

In notepad++ I thought I had added the ASCII(10)(linefeed) but apparently not. I will accept the answer by @Venkataraman R as he is correct. Thanks for your help.